# setFilteringMode in ListSelect

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Can I use [setFilteringMode of ComboBox](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/ComboBox.html#setFilteringMode%28com.vaadin.shared.ui.combobox.FilteringMode%29) in [ListSelect](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/ListSelect.html) ? I didn't found anyway to do this. I am so supprised due to this mothod didn't support in [ListSelect](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/ListSelect.html). I don't think [ComboBox](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/ComboBox.html) and [ListSelect](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/ListSelect.html) are too many differences. So , if I want to use [Filtering](https://vaadin.com/api/7.3.0/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractSelect.Filtering.html) in [ListSelect](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/ListSelect.html) , how can I figure it out ?

Comment: As FilteringMode sets, **how** the user will find items in the dropdown list (Combobox), I don't see the point of apply this to a list-select, as there is no search available at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a possible solution, you can create a textfield below your ListSelect and use a filterable container *(https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Container.Filterable.html)* as the data source of your ListSelect and apply a container filter e.g. on each "return" in this textfield or even on each text-change event.

```
    IndexedContainer c = new IndexedContainer();
    listSelect.setContainerDataSource(c);
    Filter filter = new SimpleStringFilter("name", "Douglas", true, false);
    c.addContainerFilter(filter);
```

See the [Book of Vaadin - Filterable Containers](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.container.html#datamodel.container.filtered)